# Pasting a value to a specific column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like assistance on how to paste to a specific column since I have thousands of records in Column A and need to input a certain value to Column B, is there a way to do this in excel like macro-wise?

Note that I don't have a formula in Column B, just a string value.

For example I would want to paste the value of C1 up to C3, without dragging but just by specifying C3 as the last row.

[image]

Would greatly appreciate any assistance on this. Thanks!

Comment: We need more information.. how do you achieve this **certain value**? Can you provide a sample sheet highlighting what your end goal is? On the face of it, it seems quiet simple but as I don't completely understand the question, wouldn't like to hazard a guess

Comment: Please post a data sample and explain in context. What do you want to see in which cell and what is the logic that leads to that result? Please edit your question and add more detail. You can post a screenshot. You don't have enough reputation for a screenshot to show, but if you post a comment, we will be alerted and can make the screenshot visible to all.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question seeking for assistance please, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to know how to copy something from Column A and Paste Values (the results of a formula that create a string) into column Column B, using VBA.

If cell `A1` contained the formula:

```
="abc"&"xyz"
```

...and we want the value to be copy & pasted into cell `B1`, then we could use:

```
Range("A1").Copy
Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [Range.Copy Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-copy-method-excel) (Excel)
- MSDN : [Range.PasteSpecial Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-pastespecial-method-excel) (Excel)